# Testing the Observer complete event with Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, jestjs

The RxJS `Observer` fires the events:

- `complete`
- `error`
- `next`

If we want to test for the complete event with Jest.  How is this done?

For example we can test the `next` and `error` events, because those functions pass data:

```
o.subscribe(result => {
  expect(result.data.length).toEqual(1);
}, 
(e)=>{expect(e).toBeFalsy()}, 
()=>{ WHAT TO EXPECT HERE? }
```

The `complete` event does not.  The function signature is `()=>void`.  How do we test that function signature?

Also the line `(e)=>{expect(e).toBeFalsy()}` because it never actually fires.  Is there a way to check that a callback does not run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const toPromise = obs =>
  new Promise((complete, error) => {
    obs.subscribe({ complete, error });
  });

import { getUserEvents } as user from '../user';

// The assertion for a promise must be returned.
it('works with promises', () =>
  expect(toPromise(getUserEvents(4))).resolves.toEqual('Mark'))
```

Via:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3482#issuecomment-385106653

Furthermore, since Jest will fail on Errors being thrown, you can use any testing framework inside of its test. E.g. `import 'rxjs/testing'`, [like described here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/marble-testing.md)

Answer (score 0):

[How to test that the error callback is not called is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194913/testing-callbacks-that-are-not-called-with-jest).

Looks like this will test the `complete` callback:

```
let complete = false;
let completeHandler = ()=>{
  complete = true;
  expect(complete).toBeTruthy()
};
let errorHandler = (e)=>{
  console.log("THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED");
  console.log("HOW DO WE VERIFY THAT IT IS NOT?");
let o:Observable<Result> = fn(data, errorHandler, completeHandler);
o.subscribe();
```

The `errorHandler` and `completeHandler` are baked into the `Observable<Result` returned by the `fn` function.