# Testing callbacks that are not called with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, sinon

Is there a way to test that a callback is not called with Jest?

For example:

```
o.subscribe(cb, cbError, cbComplete);
```

The `cb` and `cbComplete` callbacks should fire and the `cbError` callback should not fire.

is there a way to test that `cbError` is never called?

Comment: Sinon is a great tool for creating spy functions, alternatively you could implement it yourself, by passing a boolean flag into the function that gets switched when executed, and assert that the flag has/hasn't been changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Richard's comment:

```
let error = false;
let cbError = ()=> { error =true };
let cbComplete = ()=>{
  complete = true;
  expect(complete).toBeTruthy();
  expect(error).toBeFalsy();
  done(); //This is the async callback that Jest provides to let Jest know that the test is done.

}
```

Inside the complete callback we test that error is still `false`.  Since it's false after the Observable completes, the cbError callback was never called, because that callback is mutually exclusive from the other callbacks.

### Side Note

This sort of gives an indication that the cbError is not called.  By design the cbError and cbComplete callbacks are meant to be mutually exclusive, but we can't call `done()` from jest in both places, because it would equal a race condition in the test, so it that essentially we have to trust the design in this case. If anyone has any other thoughts on this please leave a comment.